# Minimum of maximums of non-contiguous subsequences of size k

Tags: c, algorithm, max, min, subsequence

Before I start: I hope this question is not a duplicate. I've found a couple of similar ones, but none of them seems to describe exactly the same problem. But if it is a duplicate, I will be glad to see a solution (even if it is different from my algorithm.)

---

I have been trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381470/minimum-of-maximums-for-k-size-nonconsecutive-subsequence-of-array). After a couple of attempts I managed to implement an algorithm that seems to be correct (in C). I've prepared a couple of tests and they all pass.

Now, initially I thought that the task would be easier. Therefore, I would be certain of my solution, and would publish it right after I would see it works. But I'd rather not publish an answer that presents a solution that only seems to be correct. So, I wrote a "proof of correctness", or at least something that looks like that. (I don't remember if I have ever written any proof of correctness for a program, so I'm rather certain its quality can be improved.)

So, I have two questions:

1. **Is the algorithm that I wrote correct?**
2. **Is the "proof" that I wrote correct?**

Also, I'd love to know if you have any tips on how to improve both the algorithm and the "proof" beside correctness, and maybe even the implementation (though I know C, I can always make a mistake). If either the algorithm formulations, the proof, or the C code seems too complicated to read or check, please give me some tips, and I'll try to simplify them.

And please, don't hesitate to point out that I misunderstood the problem completely if that is the case. After all, it is most important to present the right solution for the author of the original question.

I'm going to wait some time for an answer here before I publish an answer to the original question. But eventually, if there won't be any, I think I will publish it anyway.

## The problem

To quote the author of the original question:

> Suppose I have an array, arr = [2, 3, 5, 9] and k = 2. I am supposed to find subsequences of length k such that no two elements in each subsequence are adjacent. Then find the maximums of those sequences. Finally, find the minimum of the maximums. For example, for arr, the valid subsequences are [2,5], [3,9], [2,9] with maximums 5, 9, and 9 respectively. The expected output would be the minimum of the maximums, which is 5.

## My algorithm

I've made two assumptions not stated in the original question:

1. the elements of the input sequence are unique,
2. for the input subsequence length and `k`, `2 <= k <= (length(S) + 1) / 2`.

They may look a bit arbitrary, but I think that they simplify the problem a bit. When it comes to the uniqueness, I  think I could remove this assumption (so that the algorithm will suit for more use cases). But before, I need to know whether the current solution is correct.

### Pseudocode, version 1

```
find_k_length_sequence_maxes_min (S, k)
    if k < 2 or length(S) < 2 * k - 1
        return NO_SUCH_MINIMUM

    sorted = copy(S)
    sort_ascending(sorted)

    for t from 1 to length(S)
        current_length = 0

        index = find_index(S, sorted[t])

        last_index = index

        for u descending from index to 1
            if u < last_index - 1 && S[u] <= sorted[t]
                current_length += 1
                last_index = u

            if current_length >= k
                return sorted[t]

        last_index = index

        for u ascending from index to length(S)
            if u > last_index + 1 and S[u] <= sorted[t]
                current_length += 1
                last_index = u

            if current_length >= k
                return sorted[t]
```

### Pseudocode, version 2

(This is the same algorithm as in version 1, only written using more natural language.)

(1) Let `S` be a sequence of integers such that all of its elements are unique.

(2) Let a "non-contiguous subsequence of `S`" mean such a subsequence of `S` that any two elements of it are non-adjacent in `S`.

(3) Let `k` be an integer such that `2 <= k <= (length(S) + 1) / 2`.

(4) Find the minimum of maximums of all the non-contiguous subsequences of `S` of length `k`.

(4.1) Find the minimal element of `S` such that it is the maximum of a non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of size `k`.

(4.1.1) Let `sorted` be a permutation of `S` such that its elements are sorted in ascending order.

(4.1.2) For every element `e` of `sorted`, check whether it is a maximum of a non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of length `k`. If it is, return it.

(4.1.2.1) Let `x` and `y` be integers such that `1 <= x <= index(minmax(k))` and `index(minmax(k)) <= y <= length(S)`.

(4.1.2.2) Let `all(x, y)` be the set of all the non-contiguous subsequences of `S` between `S[x]` (including) and `S[y]` (including) such that `e` is the maximum of each of them.

(4.1.2.3) Check whether the length of the longest sequence of `all(1, index(e))` is greater than or equal to `k`. If it is, return `e`.

(4.1.2.4) Check whether the sum of the lengths of the longest subsequence of `all(1, index(e))` and the length of the longest subsequence of `all(index(e), length(S))` is greater than or equal to `k`. If it is, return `e`.

### Proof of correctness

(1) Glossary:

- by "observation" I mean a statement not derived from any observation or conclusion, not demanding a proof,
- by "conclusion" I mean a statement derived from at least one observation or conclusion, not demanding a proof,
- by "theorem" I mean a statement not derived from any observation or conclusion, demanding a proof.

(2) Let `S` be a sequence of integers such that all of its elements are unique.

(3) Let a "non-contiguous subsequence of `S`" mean such a subsequence of `S` that any two elements of it are non-adjacent in `S`.

(4) Let `k` be an integer such that `2 <= k <= (length(S) + 1) / 2`.

(5) Let `minmax(k)` be an element of `S` such that it is the minimum of maximums of all the non-contiguous subsequences of `S` of length `k`.

(6) (Theorem) `minmax(k)` is a minimal element of `S` such that it is a maximum of a non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of length `k`.

(7) In other words, there is no element in `S` less than `minmax(k)` that is a maximum of a non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of length `k`.

(8) (Proof of (6)) (Observation) Since `minmax(k)` is the minimum of maximums of all the non-contiguous sequences of `S` of length `k`, there is no non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of length `k` such that its maximum is greater than `minmax(k)`.

(9) (Proof of (6)) (Conclusion) If (6), then any element of `S` less than `minmax(k)` cannot be a maximum of any non-contiguous subsequence of `S` of length `k`.

(10) (Proof of (6)) QED

(11) Let `x` and `y` be integers such that `1 <= x <= index(minmax(k))` and `index(minmax(k)) <= y <= length(S)`.

(12) Let `all(x, y)` be the set of all the non-contiguous subsequences of `S` between `S[x]` (including) and `S[y]` (including) such that `minmax(k)` is the maximum of each of them.

(13) (Observation) `minmax(k)` is the maximum of the longest sequence of `all(1, length(S))`.

(14) This observation may seem too trivial to note. But, apparently it was easier for me to write the algorithm, and prove it, with the longest subsequence in mind, instead of a subsequence of length `k`. Therefore I think this observation is worth noting.

(15) (Theorem) One can produce the longest sequence of `all(1, index(minmax(k)))` by:

- starting from `minmax(k)`,
- moving to `S[1]`,
- taking always the next element that is both less than or equal to `minmax(k)`, and non-adjacent to the last taken one.

(16) (Proof of (15)) Let a "possible element" of `S` mean an element that is both less than or equal to `minmax(k)`, and non-adjacent to the last taken one.

(16a) (Proof of (15)) Let `C` be the subsequence produced in (15).

(17) (Proof of (15)) (Observation)

- Before the first taken element, there is exactly 0 possible elements,
- between any two taken elements (excluding them), there is exactly 0 or 1 possible elements,
- after the last taken element, there is exactly 0 or 1 possible elements.

(18) (Proof of (15)) Let `D` be a sequence of `all(1, index(minmax(k)))` such that `length(D) > length(C)`.

(19) (Proof of (15)) At least one of the following conditions is fulfilled:

- before the first taken element, there is less than 0 possible elements in `D`,
- between two taken elements (excluding them) such that there is 1 possible elements between them in `C`, there is 0 possible elements in `D`,
- after the last taken element, there is less than 1 possible element in `D`.

(20) (Proof of (15)) (Observation)

- There cannot be less than 0 possible elements before the first taken element,
- if there is less than 1 possible elements between two taken elements (excluding them) in `D`, where in `C` there is 1, it means that we have taken either an element greater than `minmax(k)`, or an element adjacent to the last taken one, which contradicts (12),
- if there is less than 1 possible element between the last taken element in `D`, where in `C` there is 1, it means that we have taken either an element greater than `minmax(k)`, or an element adjacent to the last taken one, which contradicts (12).

(21) (Proof of (15)) QED

(22) (Observation) (15) applies also to `all(index(minmax(k)), length(S))`.

(23) (Observation) `length(all(1, length(S))) = length(all(1, index(minmax(k)))) + length(all(index(minmax(k)), length(S)))`.

### Implementation

All the tests pass if any of the `assert` calls does not abort the program.

```c
#include <limits.h> // For INT_MAX
#include <assert.h> // For assert
#include <string.h> // For memcpy
#include <stdlib.h> // For qsort

int compar (const void * first, const void * second) {
    if (* (int *)first < * (int *)second) return -1;
    else if (* (int *)first == * (int *)second) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

void find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min (int array_length, int array[], int k, int * result_min) {
    if (k < 2 || array_length < 2 * k - 1) return;

    int sorted[array_length];
    memcpy(sorted, array, sizeof (int) * array_length);
    qsort(sorted, array_length, sizeof (int), compar);

    for (int t = 0; t < array_length; ++t) {
        int index = -1;
        while (array[++index] != sorted[t]);

        int size = 1;

        int last_index = index;
        for (int u = index; u >= 0; --u) {
            if (u < last_index - 1 && array[u] <= sorted[t]) {
                ++size;
                last_index = u;
            }

            if (size >= k) {
                * result_min = sorted[t];
                return;
            }
        }

        last_index = index;
        for (int u = index; u < array_length; ++u) {
            if (u > last_index + 1 && array[u] <= sorted[t]) {
                ++size;
                last_index = u;
            }

            if (size >= k) {
                * result_min = sorted[t];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    // Test case 1
    int array1[] = { 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 0, 9, 7, 4, 2, };
    int array1_length = (int)((double)sizeof array1 / sizeof (int));
    int k = 2;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array1_length, array1, k, & min);
    assert(min == 2);

    // Test case 2
    int array2[] = { 1, 7, 2, 3, 9, 11, 8, 14, };
    int array2_length = (int)((double)sizeof array2 / sizeof (int));
    k = 2;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array2_length, array2, k, & min);
    assert(min == 2);

    // Test case 3
    k = 3;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array2_length, array2, k, & min);
    assert(min == 8);

    // Test case 4
    k = 4;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array2_length, array2, k, & min);
    assert(min == 9);

    // Test case 5
    int array3[] = { 3, 5, 4, 0, 8, 2, };
    int array3_length = (int)((double)sizeof array3 / sizeof (int));
    k = 3;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array3_length, array3, k, & min);
    assert(min == 3);

    // Test case 6
    int array4[] = { 18, 21, 20, 6 };
    int array4_length = (int)((double)sizeof array4 / sizeof (int));
    k = 2;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array4_length, array4, k, & min);
    assert(min == 18);

    // Test case 7
    int array5_length = 1000000;
    int array5[array5_length];
    for (int m = array5_length - 1; m >= 0; --m) array5[m] = m;
    k = 100;
    min = INT_MAX;
    find_k_size_sequence_maxes_min(array5_length, array5, k, & min);
    assert(min == 198);
}
```

---

**Edit:** Thanks to [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109), the number of iterations on `sorted` may be reduced in some cases. There need to be at least `k - 1` elements less than `sorted[t]` to form a subarray of size `k` or greater together with `sorted[t]`. Therefore, in the `for` loop, it should be `int t = k - 1` instead of `int t = 0`.

**Edit:** Now that it passed a week, I published my solution as an answer in the original question: [Minimum of maximums for k-size nonconsecutive subsequence of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381470/minimum-of-maximums-for-k-size-nonconsecutive-subsequence-of-array/74733854#74733854) If you will happen to have any further tips on how to improve it, you can share them either here, or in the original question (as comments to my answer).

Comment: I read pseudocode v2 and the implementation, and I agree that your approach will generate the correct answer. One observation that I'll make is that you should be able to start with `t = k-1` instead of `t = 0`, since elements less than `sorted[k-1]` can't possibly be the largest element in a subsequence of length `k`. That doesn't change the time complexity, but will reduce the running time when `k` is large.

Comment: Yes, @user3386109, thank you for spotting this. Indeed, when I think about it now, there need to be at least `k - 1` elements less than `sorted[t]` to form a subarray of size `k` or greater together with `sorted[t]`. I won't edit the code, the pseudocode nor the proof, but I'll make an edit for others to easily see this improvement.

Comment: (PS And of course, thank you for confirming the correctness.)

Comment: Adding assumptions about the input changes the problem into a different problem.  That may very well yield an easier problem, but it's rarely an available alternative in real-world programming.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know. As I wrote, most probably I'll try to remove the first assumption in the future. The second assumption seems to be less tied with the problem as described. I included it mainly for avoiding additional validation of the input (note that beyond the limits it introduces, there is no minimum to return). Well, eventually I understand that the task in the original question may involve such validation, therefore I might removed this assumption, too.

Comment: Now that it passed a week, I published my solution as an answer in the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381470/minimum-of-maximums-for-k-size-nonconsecutive-subsequence-of-array/74733854#74733854 If you will happen to have any further tips on how to improve it, you can share them either here, or in the original question (as comments to my answer).